# bamboo build fails on bower install

Tags: bower, bamboo

I am new to CI/bamboo and am trying to run a bamboo build job for a mean stack app (angular full-stack generator). I'm running bower via a bamboo script task.
Initially I used the command:

```
bower install
```

But this gave me an error message saying that the bower.json file is missing (sorry I don't have exact error message text on-hand). The bower file is definitely in the root of the project.
Next I changed the command to:

```
bower install bower.json
```

I believe this tells bower to use bower.json file in the project root.
This successfully kicks off the bower install, but it fails and in turn fails the bamboo build job. The following appears in the log:

```
07-Jan-2016 14:52:52    bower polymer#~0.5.4             invalid-meta polymer is missing "main" entry in bower.json
07-Jan-2016 14:52:52    bower polymer#~0.5.4             invalid-meta polymer is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
07-Jan-2016 14:52:52    bower polymer#~0.5.4                 resolved https://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#0.5.6
07-Jan-2016 14:52:52    bower webcomponentsjs#^0.6.0       not-cached https://github.com/Polymer/webcomponentsjs.git#^0.6.0
07-Jan-2016 14:52:52    bower webcomponentsjs#^0.6.0          resolve https://github.com/Polymer/webcomponentsjs.git#^0.6.0
07-Jan-2016 14:52:52    bower core-component-page#^0.5     not-cached https://github.com/Polymer/core-component-page.git#^0.5
07-Jan-2016 14:52:52    bower core-component-page#^0.5        resolve https://github.com/Polymer/core-component-page.git#^0.5
07-Jan-2016 14:52:52    bower webcomponentsjs#^0.6.0         download https://github.com/Polymer/webcomponentsjs/archive/v0.6.3.tar.gz
07-Jan-2016 14:52:53    bower webcomponentsjs#~0.5.4          extract archive.tar.gz
07-Jan-2016 14:52:53    bower webcomponentsjs#~0.5.4         resolved https://github.com/Polymer/webcomponentsjs.git#0.5.5
07-Jan-2016 14:52:53    bower core-component-page#^0.5       download https://github.com/Polymer/core-component-page/archive/0.5.6.tar.gz
07-Jan-2016 14:52:56    bower core-component-page#^0.5        extract archive.tar.gz
07-Jan-2016 14:52:56    bower webcomponentsjs#^0.6.0          extract archive.tar.gz
07-Jan-2016 14:52:56    bower core-component-page#^0.5   invalid-meta core-component-page is missing "main" entry in bower.json
07-Jan-2016 14:52:56    bower core-component-page#^0.5   invalid-meta core-component-page is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
07-Jan-2016 14:52:56    bower core-component-page#^0.5       resolved https://github.com/Polymer/core-component-page.git#0.5.6
07-Jan-2016 14:52:56    bower webcomponentsjs#^0.6.0         mismatch Version declared in the json (0.6.1) is different than the resolved one (0.6.3)
07-Jan-2016 14:52:56    bower webcomponentsjs#^0.6.0         resolved https://github.com/Polymer/webcomponentsjs.git#0.6.3
07-Jan-2016 14:52:56    bower                               ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for webcomponentsjs
```

The server is Ubuntu (sorry don't have version) and bower is version 1.7.1

Here is the bower.json file:

```
bower.json:
 {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": ">=1.2.*",
    "json3": "~3.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~3.0.1",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "~3.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-resource": ">=1.2.*",
    "angular-cookies": ">=1.2.*",
    "angular-sanitize": ">=1.2.*",
    "angular-route": ">=1.2.*",
    "font-awesome": ">=4.1.0",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "select2": "~4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": ">=1.2.*",
    "angular-scenario": ">=1.2.*"
  }
}
```

The project has a .bowerrc file:

```
.bowerrc:
{
    "directory": "client/bower_components"
}
```

I tried to simulate the bower task on my home pc (Ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and bower 1.7.1) by running 'bower install' and it runs without issue. But if I specify the bower.json file in the command 'bower install bower.json' I get prompted for the following:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for webcomponentsjs, please choose one:
    1) webcomponentsjs#~0.5.4 which resolved to 0.5.5 and is required by App States#0.6.9
    2) webcomponentsjs#* which resolved to 0.5.5 and is required by core-component-page#0.5.6
    3) webcomponentsjs#^0.6.0 which resolved to 0.6.3 and is required by polymer#0.5.6
```

Not sure if this behavior is related to the bamboo issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: I gave you an answer; did it work?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the version for the conflicting `webcomponentsjs` explicitely in your `bower.json`. While bower can ask you which dependency to use when running from an interactive shell, this is obviously not possible when running the task on Bamboo.